# How can I get some words in string with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove all the characters outside '(*)'.
How can I make code for the result?

```
string = "hello (hi) this (is) my (questions)";
=> "(hi)(is)(questions)"
```

Comment: You mentionned regex in the tags, what've you tried?

Comment: Little hint: `\((.*?)\)`

Comment: You should add the code that you already tried and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This regex selects the characters not outside (*) `\(+\w+\)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `match` (comments inline)

```js
var string = "hello (hi) this (is) my (questions)";

var matches = string.match(/\([^)]*\)/g); //match all those string which begins with ( and end with ) and there is no ) in between

var output = matches ? matches.join( "" ) : ""; //check if there is any match

console.log ( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way could be to match with `\((.*?)\)` which gives you array of matched words and then `join` it using `''`

```js
var string = "hello (hi) this (is) my (questions)";
var matched = string.match(/\((.*?)\)/g);
matched = matched.join('');
console.log(matched);
```